# -bash: psql: command not found

Tags: macos, mac, psql

I'm on a Mac 10.11 running `psql -h localhost -U monitor -W postgres` and I kept getting

## `-bash: psql: command not found`

---

This is what I have in my paths.

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/pgsql/bin
```

Comment: How did you install pgsql ?

Comment: I install a Mac app call `postgres`

Comment: I usually prefer to use a package manager such as homebrew or fink, anyway I'll try to give you a hand, is it the one you have installed http://postgresapp.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. That is the one.

Comment: did you export the PATH? ```export PATH=$PATH://Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin```

Comment: No. Should I do it ?

Comment: Yes you want to follow the instructions from this page http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html in clear just export your path and then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. I will try it tmr at work, and update you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Postgres using Postgres app then you need to add psql in your path. Change the Postgres version in the following command.

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/:$PATH
```

Or you can add the above line in `~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile`

and then execute the following command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

https://www.installvirtual.com/question/psql-command-not-found-mac/